# Measurable indicator for usability

Tags: requirements-management

I am starting a new project and I have the problem with the measurability of the requirement usability.

With is an good atomic measurable indicator for usability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of klicks or keystrokes per action, weighted with the estimated relative frequency of the action.

However, this metric does not take into account a few important aspects of usability:

- How easy it is to memorize the sequence of clicks and keystrokes
- The amount of feedback provided to the user
- The likelyhood of invalid inputs

Still it can be useful for comparing user interfaces that are similar with respect to these aspects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think its a good idea to weight the klicks with the amount of use of an action. May be I can combine that with a factor for every kind of used gui elements such as text boxes, drop down menus and so on which says how easy it is to use.